# GET List of Privileged Role Assignments fails with "UnknownError"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I've got an app registration in Azure with the required permission - Directory.AccessAsUser.All (delegated) and that registration has Security Reader over all of my subscriptions.

When I `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedRoles/{id}/assignments` with my access token (bearer auth), I get the following response:

```
{
  error: { 
    code: 'UnknownError',
    message: '',
    innerError: { 
      'request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        date: '2020-03-13T11:53:41' 
    } 
  }
}
```

The {id} in this case is the ID of the permission I want check the assignments of.

I'm using this as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedrole-list-assignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Hi, could it solve your issue?

Comment: Sadly no in my case. I was after an automated review with my implementation - so just used the builtin AAD PIM access reviews

Answer (score 0):

This is a `beta` version API, the current endpoints of AAD roles have been disabled for your tenant for migration purpose, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/azure-ad-roles-features#api-changes).

> When customers have the updated version rolled out to their Azure AD organization, the existing graph API will stop working. You must transition to use the [Graph API for Azure resource roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedidentitymanagement-resources?view=graph-rest-beta). To manage Azure AD roles using that API, swap `/azureResources` with `/aadroles` in the signature and use the Directory ID for the resourceId.

So you need to use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroleassignment-list?view=graph-rest-beta) currently, swap `/azureResources` with `/aadroles`, test it in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/aadRoles/resources/<tenant-id>/roleAssignments?$filter=RoleDefinitionId+eq+'RoleDefinitionId'
```

[image]